# Does the Empire have any advantages over the Rebel Alliance, or vice versa?

Tags: star-wars-commander

I have a friend that says that AT-AT's are better than the Rebel's equivalent Juggernaut in Star Wars Commander because the AT-AT's now shoot the edge of a shield - he also believes their damage is higher. This leads me to ask, do the factions in this game have specific advantages over eachother?

Do rebel basic troops have more health or deal more damage than stormtroopers? Are there any real combat differences between the two factions?

Answer (score 1):

Both sides have different pros and cons. The makers permanently add new features and try to balance the game.

The rebels have medic droids, the empire has that Hero At-At...

Answer (score -1):

In this game you can choose either the **Rebels** or the **Empire**.

You should keep in mind that the Rebels have stronger infantry compared to that of the Empire while the Empire's machinery is stronger compared to the Rebels.

While the Empire have slightly inferior infantry, they have access to  advanced machinery that can mow down any defense.  If you are a Rebel you should put 60% rocket turrets to finish off the machines and 40% mortar turrets to wipe out the infantry and medic droids assisting the machines.